# Why does my HTML select menu disappear as soon as I import another javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql

I coded with some help a select menu which looks like this in the first picture. My idea was that when the user presses "Next", my Website sends a SQL request to a database and gives back the first artist who matches the genre the user chose. I have a HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom Select Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="genre" id="musicGenre">
        <h2>Choose your favorite Music Genre::</h2>

        <form action="">
            <select name="musicGenre" class="musicGenre">
                <option value="hiphop">HipHop</option>
                <option value="classic">Classic Music</option>
                <option value="pop">Pop</option>
                <option value="techno">Techno</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <button onclick="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div id="result" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Result:</h2>
        <p id="artistResult"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my main.js:

```
var genre;

class MusicGenre {
    constructor(originalSelect) {
        this.originalSelect = originalSelect;
        this.customSelect = document.createElement("div");
        this.customSelect.classList.add("genreSelect");

        this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(optionElement => {
            const itemElement = document.createElement("div");

            itemElement.classList.add("select__item");
            itemElement.textContent = optionElement.textContent;
            this.customSelect.appendChild(itemElement);

            if (optionElement.selected) {
                this._select(itemElement);
            }

            itemElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (
                    this.originalSelect.multiple
                    && itemElement.classList.contains("select__item--selected")
                ) {
                    this._deselect(itemElement);
                } else {
                    this._select(itemElement);
                    genre = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);
                }
            });
        });

        this.originalSelect.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", this.customSelect);
        this.originalSelect.style.display = "none";
    }

    _select(itemElement) {
        const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

        if (!this.originalSelect.multiple) {
            this.customSelect.querySelectorAll(".select__item").forEach(element => {
                element.classList.remove("select__item--selected")
            });
        }

        this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = true;
        itemElement.classList.add("select__item--selected");
    }

    _deselect(itemElement) {
        const index = Array.from(this.customSelect.children).indexOf(itemElement);

        this.originalSelect.querySelectorAll("option")[index].selected = false;
        itemElement.classList.remove("select__item--selected");
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".musicGenre").forEach(selectElement => {
    new MusicGenre(selectElement);
})

function nextStep() {
    document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("artTypeCategory").style.display = "none";
    
    const result = await getArtistName(genre+1);
    const prompText = JSON.stringify(result[0]);

    document.getElementById("artTypeResult").innerHTML = promptText;
}
```

my main.css:

```
.genreSelect{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 1px;
}

.select__item{
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    transition: background 0.1s;
}

.select__item--selected{
    background: #009578;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

and my database.js:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2'

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'artist'
}).promise()

export async function getArtistName(id) {
    const [rows] = await pool.query(`
    SELECT Name
    FROM Artists
    WHERE ID = ?
    `, id)
    return rows
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: selection menu]

To use the function `getArtistName(id)` in main.js, I need to import this function. When I write `import { getArtistName } from "./database.js"` on the top of my main.js, my menu always looks like this:

[image: new view of the selection menu]

The "Next" button does not work as well and I get no SQL result. Does anyone know why this import command completely destroys my code?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

1- mysql2 is a library for nodejs

2- you are getting the pool using a promise but not waiting for the promise result, and that is probably why your code is failing because you must have a handler to that promise.

If you open the dev tools of your browser you can probably see the error, and work on that error.